# Plotly: How to adjust size of markers in a scatter geo map so that differences become more visible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, plotly, bubble-chart

I used library Plotly in Python: chart: Bubble-Map to display average_score of countries. However, average_score has values between 2-4 and therefore the size of the bubbles in the bubble-map chart does not differentiate much (the size of bubbles is very similar). How can I achieve a bigger difference among bubbles with values 2-4?

Here is my piece of code:

```
plot = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="country_code", color="country_code", size_max=20,hover_name="country_code", size="avg_score", animation_frame="year", projection="natural earth",title="Bubble Map",labels={"country_code": "Country"})
```

Answer (score 3):

I would raise your raw data to the power of a number that suits the visualization you're aiming to build. This makes larger numbers look disproportionally larger than sall numbers. Compare the two plots below where the first is the `px.scatter_geo()` example from the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/#geographical-scatter-plot-with-pxscattergeo), and the second where the same data for population `df['pop']` has been replaced with `df['pop']**1.6`.

#### 1. Raw data for `df['pop']`

[image]

#### 1. Data for `df['pop']` raised to the power of `1.6`

[image]

Of course these numbers have no other business in the figure, so you will have to include the following in order to keep the correct hoverinfo:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = 'pop=%{text}<br>iso_alpha=%{location}<extra></extra>', text = df['pop'])
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
df['pop_display'] = df['pop']**1.6
fig = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                     size="pop_display", 
                     )
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = 'pop=%{text}<br>iso_alpha=%{location}<extra></extra>', text = df['pop'])
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not really a Plotly question but a general math question.

Given the inputs [2,3,4] step=1. return corresponding integers that have step > 1. There are multiple ways you can accomplish this:
One way is to multiply all items by  an integer.

```
[2,3,4] * 2 = [4, 6, 8] # step=2
[2,3,4] * 3 = [6, 9, 12] # step=3
...
```

In this case the difference between new values will rise linearly. Meaning that the step between all values will remain constant.
If you want step to grow in a non linear way you can square the items:

```
[2,3,4]^2  = [4, 9, 16] # step=5, 7...
[2,3,4]^3= [8, 27, 64] # step=19,37...
...
```

Possibilities are really endless. It all depends on what kind of difference you want between the bubbles. In code, quick and dirty solution will look something like this:

---

```
plot = px.scatter_geo(df,
                      locations="country_code",
                      color="country_code", 
                      size_max=20,
                      hover_name="country_code",
                      size=df["avg_score"]**2,
                      animation_frame="year",
                      projection="natural earth",
                      title="Bubble Map",
                      labels={"country_code": "Country"}
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Geom! :) I appreciate your explanation and options.